# Text disappeared after taking style from database params

Tags: joomla-2.5, php, database

I've decided to extract the params for my module directly from the database, to put them in my variable stylesheet. I know this is not the recommended way, but for learning sake I find this to be a good test.

I am doing this like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName('params'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__modules'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('module') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('mod_ext_superfish_menu'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadResult();
$params = json_decode($results);

var_dump($params);
```

This works well and I do get all the variables into my CSS.  all the text that used to be in my list items, has now disappeared-- so, the styling is right, but the text that's supposed to be in the styled items has vanished. What have I done wrong?

To add, the styling is done as such:

```
.menu {
    line-height:    1.0;

    <?php // WIDTH
    if($params->menuWidth != "") {
        echo "width: ".$params->gmenuWidth."px;";
    } 
    ?>

    <?php // HEIGHT
    if($params->menuHeight != "") {
        echo "height: ".$params->menuHeight."px;";
    }
    ?>



    <?php //margin top & margin left 
    if($params->menuMarginLeft != "") {
    echo "margin-left: ".$params->menuMarginLeft."px; ";
}
if($params->menuMarginTop != "") {
    echo "margin-top: ".$params->menuMarginTop."px; ";
}
?>
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply add CSS to your PHP file and expect it to work.

For example, the following will just **NOT** work:

```
<?php  
   .menu {
       font-size: 12px;
   }
?>
```

I have already in a previous answer explained how to use `addStyleDeclaration()`. I know you're trying to learn which is great, but when someone recommends a method, don't ignore it ;)

So, firstly, remove all your code and add the following:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$css = '.menu { line-height: 1.0; }';

if($params->menuWidth != '') {
    $css .= '.menu { width: ' . $params->gmenuWidth . 'px; }';
}
if($params->menuHeight != '') {
    $css .= '.menu { height: ' . $params->menuHeight . 'px; }';
}
if($params->menuMarginLeft != '') {
    $css .= '.menu { margin-left: ' . $params->menuMarginLeft . 'px; }';
}
if($params->menuMarginTop != '') {
    $css .= '.menu { margin-top: ' . $params->menuMarginTop . 'px; }';
} 

$doc->addStyleDeclaration($css);
```

You will see above the first `$css` is as is. But the other ones inside the `if` statements have a `.` before the `=` symbol. This means that the variable name be be used multiple times without having an effect on eachother.

Finally, for adding CSS that has value based on variables/parameters, stick to this method and **do not** use any other method.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -4):

Actually it does work :) Here's what I did:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName('params'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__modules'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('module') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('mod_ext_superfish_menu'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadResult();

//var_dump($results);

$params = json_decode($results);

var_dump($params);


/*** MAIN MENU SETTINGS ***/

.<?php echo $module->module; //div name is equal to module ?> {

font-size: <?php if($params->fontSize != "") { echo "".$params->fontSize."px;"; } else { echo "14px;"; } ?>

background-color: <?php  
    if($params->entireMenuBgColor != "") {
        echo "".$params->entireMenuBgColor.";";
    }
?>

<?php 
    if($params->backgroundImage != "-1") {
        echo "background-image: url('". JURI::ROOT(false, "")."images/menu/".$params->backgroundImage."');";
    }

?>

background-repeat: repeat-x;

<?php if($params->fontStyle != "") {
    echo $params->fontStyle;    
} else { 
    echo "normal"; 
}   ?>

<?php if($params->fontFamily != "") {
    echo "fontFamily: ".$params->fontFamily."";
}   ?>

}


.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
    margin:             0;
    padding:            0;
    list-style:         none;
    <?php if($params->textPushEffect == 1 ) {
        echo "text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.7);";
    }  ?>
} etc etc
```

Comment: This is a comment to another answer, not an answer to the question.

Comment: -1 purely due to the bad coding practices having already provided you with the answer

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.